# Simpler way to print array items into list items (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

going through some exercises in a book. Had to print out array items into a list element.

This was the solution supplied by the book.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Temperatures</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function showTemps() {
      var tempByHour = new Array();
      tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
      tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
      tempByHour[2] = 63;
      tempByHour[3] = 65;
      tempByHour[4] = 62;
      for (var i = 0; i < tempByHour.length; i++) {
        var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
        var id = "temp" + i;
        var li = document.getElementById(id);
        if (i == 0) {
          li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon was " + theTemp;
        } else {
          li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + [i] + " was " + theTemp;
        }
      }
    }
    window.onload = showTemps;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Temperatures</h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="temp0"></li>
    <li id="temp1"></li>
    <li id="temp2"></li>
    <li id="temp3"></li>
    <li id="temp4"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried going against the book's solution at first and tried to just use a for loop and use the create element method and have the messages print out alongside with them that way but had no luck.

```
var messageGen = function() {
var forecastByHour = [32, 15, 19, 25, 21];


for (var i =0; i <= forecastByHour.length; i++) {
  var temp = forecastByHour[i];
  var message = "On the " + [i] + " hour the expected forcase is to be" + temp;
  var listItems = document.createElement("li");

    listItems.innerHTML = message
}

}
```

Anybody have a simpler solution to this?

Comment: you've shown the code that works, mentioned an abstract code that doesn't, and expect help with code you haven't posted - good luck ... also, you use the word `print` - there's nothing in the code that would `print` anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fancy Array manipulation functions like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to efficiently construct HTML and manipulate your `temperatures`. This code is much easier to follow than the posted solution once you understand the higher-level methods behind it (see the linked MDN documentation pages).

```js
function showTemperatures() {
  var temperatures = [59.2, 60.1, 63, 65, 62].map(function (t, i) {
    return 'The temperature at ' + (i || 'noon') + ' was ' + t
  })

  document.getElementById('temperatures').innerHTML =
    '<li>' + temperatures.join('</li><li>') + '</li>'
}

showTemperatures()
```

```html
<h1>Temperatures</h1>
<ul id="temperatures"></ul>
```

Comment: Ooh, this does seem pretty sweet. Will definitely look into it, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this problem:

1. Make an array of data.
2. Create a function to produce an li based on parameters.
3. Use a for loop to appendChild a li to your target ul element.

```js
var tempByHour = [ 59.2, 60.1, 63, 65, 62 ];

function createLi(temp, i) {
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    
    if (i === 0) {
        li.innerText = "The temperature at noon was " + temp;
    } else {
        li.innerText = "The temperature at " + i + "was " + temp;
    }
    
    return li;
}

var i,
    len = tempByHour.length,
    target = document.getElementById("temps");

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    target.appendChild(createLi(tempByHour[i], i));
}
```

```html
<h1>Temperatures</h1>
<ul id="temps"></ul>
```

I use for loops instead of maps or forEach loops. If you benchmark the different methods, for loops are ~60% fast than maps & ~80% faster than forEach loops.

Comment: `forEach` and `map` may be slightly less performant, but for most applications, the loss in speed is more than compensated for by the added readability.

Comment: Gotcha! Will keep this one in my back pocket. Thank you!

Comment: I know we're talking fractions of a millisecond in this situation, but it does add up certain situations. Such as  high traffic web APIs. I personally always try to right the most performant code I can, for loops are rather easy to read if you structure them well.